# Inequation in Sobolev

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $u\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$.

I need to prove that:

$\|(\nabla u)u\|_{W^{0,2}(\Omega)}\leq \|\nabla u\|_{W^{0,4}(\Omega)}\;\|u\|_{W^{0,4}(\Omega)}$

I'm using the usual Sobolev notation (see for example wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \lVert f \rVert_{W^{0,2}(\Omega)} = \left(\int_{\Omega} \lvert f \rvert^2\right)^{1/2} = \lVert f \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}. $$
Hölder's inequality is
$$ \left\lvert \int_{\Omega} f g \right\rvert \leqslant \left( \int_{\Omega} \lvert f \rvert^2 \right)^{1/2} \left( \int_{\Omega} \lvert g \rvert^2 \right)^{1/2} \,  $$
or
$$ \lVert f g \rVert_{L^1(\Omega)} \leqslant \lVert f \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)} \lVert g \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}. $$
It should be fairly clear what to do from here by mucking about with the indices.